# How do I switch from local host : 3000 to something ready for production in Flutter using dio?

Tags: flutter, dio, mux-video

I am using dio to make a network request. In testing phases I was using local host port 3000. I was using a javascript file and node to run it in testing mode. I would simply run node on the javascript file it would fire up the port at it would work. This was great but whenever I run it on a real device it does not work. So I am assuming I need to change it to something else for release...? I am new bare with me. Any suggestion or guidance would be helpful thank you.

```
const muxServerUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';


 initializeDio() {
    BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: muxServerUrl,
      connectTimeout: 8000,
      receiveTimeout: 5000,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": contentType, // application/json
      },
    );
    _dio = Dio(options);
  }
```

**Implementation**

```
late Response response;
try {

  // print(response);
  response = await _dio.post(
    "/assets",
    data: {
      "videoUrl": videoUrl,
    },
  );
} catch (e) {
    print('ran 2');

  throw Exception('Failed to store video on MUX');
}

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('ran 4');
  VideoData videoData = VideoData.fromJson(response.data);

  String status = videoData.data!.status;

  while (status == 'preparing') {
  
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    videoData = (await checkPostStatus(videoId: videoData.data!.id))!;
    status = videoData.data!.status;
  }

  print('Video READY, id: ${videoData.data!.id}');

  return videoData;
}
```

**That Node Temp JS file**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Mux = require("@mux/mux-node");
const { Video } = new Mux(
  process.env.MUX_TOKEN_ID,
  process.env.MUX_TOKEN_SECRET
);
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post("/assets", jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
  console.log("BODY: " + req.body.videoUrl);

  const asset = await Video.Assets.create({
    input: req.body.videoUrl,
    playback_policy: "public",
  });

  res.json({
    data: {
      id: asset.id,
      status: asset.status,
      playback_ids: asset.playback_ids,
      created_at: asset.created_at,
    },
  });
});

app.get("/assets", async (req, res) => {
  const assets = await Video.Assets.list();

  res.json({
    data: assets.map((asset) => ({
      id: asset.id,
      status: asset.status,
      playback_ids: asset.playback_ids,
      created_at: asset.created_at,
      duration: asset.duration,
      max_stored_resolution: asset.max_stored_resolution,
      max_stored_frame_rate: asset.max_stored_frame_rate,
      aspect_ratio: asset.aspect_ratio,
    })),
  });
});

app.get("/asset", async (req, res) => {
  let videoId = req.query.videoId;
  const asset = await Video.Assets.get(videoId);

  console.log(asset);

  res.json({
    data: {
      id: asset.id,
      status: asset.status,
      playback_ids: asset.playback_ids,
      created_at: asset.created_at,
      duration: asset.duration,
      max_stored_resolution: asset.max_stored_resolution,
      max_stored_frame_rate: asset.max_stored_frame_rate,
      aspect_ratio: asset.aspect_ratio,
    },
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Mux API listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is what's called your loopback address and that's only working because you are running the application on your machine. When you release the app you have to host your Nodejs app in some server and use the IP address of that server instead. Before you host that app I encourage you to spend more time making sure that it secure.

If you just want to run the app on an Android emulator you can use `10.0.2.2` to reach the hosting machine loopback

Comment: Ok I am currently using a service called host stinger. So When I give it the url for it to go to. Would it be to the main.js. I will defintely look more into sercurity thank you.

Comment: When you say service do you mean cloud hosting? Since you are using Nodejs you just need to run your app in the VPS and change the port to 80 you would need to set up certification, and what not, but you can look that up.

Comment: Ok thank you I think I have the service you speaking of. It has ram, cores, and runs files. So I think thats fits all the criteria for virtual machine. http://polaristech.tech/files/mux/mux-api-server/ is where they are located so if I use this as my url it says it connects but it does not run the actions need to api

Comment: No you are ought to remove that link. You don't serve your javascript files. In Nodejs, javascript runs on the server. You just need to ssh into that vps and run your node app, and then use the ip address after changing to port 80. You need to look up Nodejs deployment.